# Using multiple applicationContexts with duplicate bean ids from different jar files in a webApplication

Tags: spring

I have bean1 and bean2 defined in applicationContext1 in jar1 and have bean1 (of course a different class) and bean3 defined in applicationContext2 in jar2

I need to use both jar1 and jar2 in my webapplication, which also has an applicationContext3.

I use the below entries in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>applicationContext1.xml
            <param-value>applicationContext2.xml
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/properties/application/applicationContext3.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Is there a way to prefix the applicationContext IDs so that they dont step over each other;
for eg:
in applicationContext3 can I have

```
<bean id="myBean" >
  <property name="bean1" ref="ac1:bean1">
  <property name="bean2" ref="ac2:bean1">
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could arrange it somehow (Spring is very flexible and powerful) but I think you should clean up a little your contexts. 
If you are in total control of both libraries and the main app, I would recommend creating only a main applicationContext and copying the relevant beans from the JARs.

Other good solution is to separate every applicationContext in context modules, like repository-context.xml, business-context.xml, etc and reference only the ones you need, so you have more control over what is getting loaded.

Also, take a look at this:
http://www.gridshore.nl/2008/05/13/spring-application-context-loading-tricks/